# How to stop execution of click event from onchange event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, jquery-events

In the following example https://jsfiddle.net/anu4nits/449d5j8e/

```
<input type="text" id="in" />
<input type="button" value="click" id="button" />
$('#in').change(function () {
    console.log('change event');
    dialog.dialog("open");
});
$('#button').on('click', function (e) {
    console.log('click event');
});
```

I have attached two events one is `onchange` event on text and other is click event on button. If I write something in textbox and clicks on button then handler of change event and handler of click event should get executed respectively. But as I am invoking the modal-dialog in the handler of change event, handler of click event is not getting executed, which is expected as modal- dialog won't allow any background activity. But this is only with Chrome and Mozilla. In IE handler for both the events are getting executed.

I want consistent behaviour for all browsers preferably I don't want click handler execution in IE. I also don't want to put some flag at global level for condition checking. Also I can't detach the event from button as in my application button ID and its handler are generating at runtime. **Is there any other way I can stop the execution of click event from the handler of change event.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click and Change both are separate events and they have their own stack. So you can't stop propagation of one from another as their target element are also different.
What you can do is to attach event at their common parent so that you have a common handler for them. There you can set flag and perform what you want.

Answer (score 0):

use stopPropagation, but easier solution is to go with a flag

```
$('#in').change(function(e) {
  console.log('change event');
  dialog.dialog("open");
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: click and change both are separate events u cant stop propagation of one from another in this way. Your code will stop propagation only onchange event up in dom tree

Comment: try that script. It will prevent from triggering click event as change event occurs first

Comment: In which browser u executed this??

Comment: u must have tried it in chrome ....in chrome its already not getting executed the problem is with IE

Comment: stopPropagation is supposed to work but since your click event is binded dynamically it cannot http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Comment: As per Description" Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event" but here both the events are different and under dom tree nodes are siblings. stoppropagation can't do anything here

Comment: use a flag, go for quickest way

Answer (score 0):

I needed to prevent from immediate execution of a next function defined in the same `onchange`, e.g.:

```
<input onchange="Dont(this);Work()">link</input>
```

Here I needed the Dont() to conditionally stop all further functions like the Work(). I simply threw an exception, because anything else didn't work.

```
function Dont(button){
    if($(button).data("somecondition")){
        throw "NeedToStopEveryFurtherCodeExecution!";
    }
}
```

The event.stopImmediatePropagation(); didn't help. I'm not sure why but I think there is an issue when using an external .js file.

I think this is simpler than to workaround this using conditions in every function that may be passed in the onchange. I hope this is not a really bad/deprecated way.