# How to trigger only one event 'change' or 'click'

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, event-handling

I have a number input tag on which I have two event listeners 'on-click' and 'on-change'. When I am click on arrow it triggers both. I would like to have one whichever triggers first without removing any of the event listeners.
On clicking rapidly change event doesn't trigger until it looses focus from input tag(If I keep only change event). If I keep only click event then I won't be able to capture change event.

```
<input type="number" @click="function()" @change="function()" />
```

Comment: Please add some code you have tried.

Comment: Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Observables. You can think about them as streams for events. Debouncing the output should give the result you want.

```
var event_a = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousemove'); 
var event_b = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click'); // or in this case (input_element, 'click')

var debounce_ms = 100;
var debounced_event = merge(event_a, event_b).debounceTime(debounce_ms);
```

The debouncing step removes multiple events that happen in the specified time interval. If both events (or more than one copy of the same event) happens in less than 100 ms, only one event will be emitted.

On debouncing Observables: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debouncetime.html

The above example uses different events from yours; just adapt it to listen to any of the events that you want. Lastly, subscribe to the Observable, and call the relevant event handling code there:

```
debounced_event.subscribe(() => {
    // do event handling things here
});
```

To use Observables on your page, include rx.js somewhere. Here is example code to load it from a CDN.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.1/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Comment: It worked thanks
I tried it in this way
https://plnkr.co/edit/UNx2sK2FeCPwLWqI1GBK?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can add to data a boolian
(e.g isInvoked:false).
When the function run check:

`if (this.isInvoked) return;
    this.isInvoked=true;
    //rest of your code here.....`

Comment: I tried this approach but problem is method is not invoked concurrently. "isInvoked " needs to be set to false as method completes.

Comment: Ok. Can you explain what you trying to achieve? Maybe onBlur or onInput will be more effective..

Comment: Also take a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26775955/how-to-stop-execution-of-click-event-from-onchange-event-handler.